# The barcode scanner goes stuck at the first time usage in ios,and while in the second click it works fine

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

hi I am using phonegap barcodeplugin `wildabeast/BarcodeScanner` for scanning the barcodes.

Here is my code

```
$('#scanbtn').on( "tap", function(evt){

                    scanner = null;

                    if(ival == 0){
                        ival = 1;
                        scanaction();

                    }

            });

            function scanaction(){
                cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function (result) {

                        scanText = result.text;
                        scanFormat = result.format;
                        scanCancelled = result.cancelled;

                    /* alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                                "Result: " + scanText + "\n" +
                                "Format: " + scanFormat + "\n" +
                                "Cancelled: " + scanCancelled); */

                                $.mobile.changePage('#pageTwo',{transition: "slide"});


                    }, function (error) {
                        ival = 0;
                        console.log("Scanning failed: ", error);

                    });
            }
```

[image: This is the screen I'm getting on the first scan,and the scanner goes stuck,and not scanning anymore]

And the log I'm getting on this occasion is

```
    2014-05-23 10:41:26.629 ShareQ[283:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x155ba090> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
    2014-05-23 10:41:26.735 ShareQ[283:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x155ba090> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.300 ShareQ[283:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x155ba090> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.310 ShareQ[283:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x155392f0> on <MainViewController: 0x1559e3c0> while a presentation is in progress!
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.321 ShareQ[283:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x1553bb20> on <MainViewController: 0x1559e3c0> while a presentation is in progress!
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.324 ShareQ[283:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x1553d2b0> on <MainViewController: 0x1559e3c0> while a presentation is in progress!
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.326 ShareQ[283:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x155418b0> on <MainViewController: 0x1559e3c0> while a presentation is in progress!
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.328 ShareQ[283:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x155456f0> on <MainViewController: 0x1559e3c0> while a presentation is in progress!
    2014-05-23 10:41:27.331 ShareQ[283:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x155fa710> on <MainViewController: 0x1559e3c0> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Comment: @Amit Prajapati  thanks for your edit. Do you know how to solve my issue?

Comment: which phonegap version you are working ? and which ios device you have tested this.

Comment: I have used phonegap 3.4.0 and tested on ios4(iphone) and ios7(ipad)

Comment: please use this plugin on device ready

Comment: Plugin is used in deviceready but the issue persists

Comment: Issue solved by changing the "tap" method

Comment: issue is not tap, its is off event, your click event

Comment: Yes,The event fires multiple times, I've changed the method as follows, Now it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the jquerymobile framework.
The "tap" function in the jquerymobile fires multiple times on a single click was the reason for the issue I've mensioned. It is rectified by changing the jquerymobile's "tap" method as follows

```
    $(document).off('tap', '#scanbtn')
                          .on('tap', '#scanbtn',function(e) {
                                   if(ival == 0){
                                          ival = 1;
                                          scanaction();

                                    }

                             });
```

Now my issue is solved. The scanner works fine.

Comment: Anand, may I ask you to post the link to the specific wildabeast/BarcodeScanner plugin you are using. The one I was using fails in Phonegap 3.4.0.

Comment: @Ric sorry for the delay the url is [https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner]

Comment: yes, magically, I found that rebuilding the Cordova app using Cordova 3.5.0 did the trick and the barcode scanner now works. Since Cordova changed and the scanner code did not I would have to believe I have been Wrestling the problem at the wrong end. Sure makes me wary of updating Cordova again on the next small rev.

Comment: @Ric Ohh, it sounds great,glad to hear that your issue is solved.